# Delete the Consumer group of Kafka with SSL enabled

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am using below command to delete the Consumer group of Kafka with SSL enabled. This works fine but the problem is that I don't want to save password in ***client-ssl.properties*** file instead I should be able to pass the password dynamically to this command something like "*--override ssl.keystore.password 12345*" option. I tried using --override option but it does not works.

Please let us know how to override the values present in client-ssl.properties file or is there any way where I can delete the Consumer group without saving the password in a file.

**Command:**

`kafka\bin\kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9093 --command-config \kafka\config\client-ssl.properties --delete --group ABCD`

**client-ssl.properties file:**

```
security.protocol=SSL
ssl.truststore.location=/server.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=12345
ssl.keystore.location=/server.keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=12345
```

Answer (score 0):

If the concern is the need for putting a password in plaintext on disk, then the only workaround would be to write your own utility that calls the same method as that shell script and dynamically get the password from somewhere else

Note that consumer groups automatically delete themselves over time if they are inactive

Comment: regarding Consumer groups automatically delete themselves : Is there a configuration property where we can set the time to gets expired ? Because, I created a consumer group and it is been inactive for 4 days, now it's state is EMPTY with Members = 0, which means it is Inactive but when I query the list of Consumers then I am still this group name in the list. So, please let me know if the consumer groups really gets deleted ?

Comment: It's determined by the offsets retention settings in the broker config